# Groupby a column from another (same # of rows) dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have two simple data frames:

```
x1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4],
                   'b':[10,10,20,20],  
                   'c':['z','z','z','o']})
x2 = pd.DataFrame({'e':['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'], 
                   'f':['baz', 'blah', 'baz', 'blah']})
> x1
   a   b  c
0  1  10  z
1  2  10  z
2  3  20  z
3  4  20  o
> x2
     e     f
0  foo   baz
1  bar  blah
2  foo   baz
3  foo  blah
```

I want to apply a function to groups of `x1` based on the columns in `x2`. e.g.:

```
x1['avg'] = x1.groupby(x2[['e', 'f']])['a'].transform(np.mean)
*** ValueError: Grouper for '<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>' not 1-dimensional
```

But I get this value error.

The error doesn't occur if the groupby split is coming from x1 (but I don't want to have to assign `x2` columns to `x1`, for code cleanliness reasons I won't get into.

```
x1.groupby(['b', 'c'])['a'].transform(np.mean)
0    1.5
1    1.5
2    3.0
3    4.0
```

Why is this happening / can I get around it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pass a DataFrame, but you can pass a (list of) Series:

```
In [11]: x1.groupby([x2.e, x2.f])["a"].transform("mean")
Out[11]:
0    2
1    2
2    2
3    4
dtype: int64
```

More generally you could do this with a list comprehension (if you're grouping by all the columns in another DataFrame):

```
In [12]: x1.groupby([x2[col] for col in x2])["a"].transform("mean")
Out[12]:
0    2
1    2
2    2
3    4
dtype: int64
```

*That said, it may be better to go ahead and do the join... IMO it's often a good idea to keep your variables independent.*

Comment: Funnily enough, neither this not @Alexander's solution below works in 0.19.x... Perhaps a pandas bug that broke this?

Comment: @Kartik this works for me in 0.19.1 ! (Alexander's doesn't, but perhaps that's a python 3 issue... I get a zip not callable, or if I make it a list `GroupByError: len(index) != len(labels)` as I commented previously)

Comment: Yeah, it was a 0.19.0 specific issue. I thought I had updated my env, but guess not. [Here is the question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40986701/3765319) I asked, and subsequently voted to close.

Answer (score 3):

You can zip the two columns together and pass the paired tuples to your `groupby`.

```
>>> x1.groupby(zip(x2['e'], x2['f']))['a'].transform(np.mean)
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

Comment: I *think* doing the zip is going to be inefficient here.

Comment: Possibly.  I believe your solution is cleaner, why is why I upvoted it.  But I don't understand why our results are different.

Comment: Interesting!! Also this `x1.groupby(list(zip(x2['e'], x2['f'])))["b"].transform("mean")` gives me a `GroupByError: len(index) != len(labels)` which looks incorrect to me. Surely a pandas bug...

Comment: Worked fine for me using 0.17.1.  I'm still not clear, however, on what is being grouped.  Try `x1.groupby([x2.e, x2.f])["a"].sum()` to see what I mean.  Then try `pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1, 11), columns=['A']).groupby([x2.e, x2.f])["A"].sum()`