# How to group a pandas DataFrame using another?

Tags: python, pandas

This seems easy enough to do, but I cannot make it work. Here is a short example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Creating a DataFrame with a timeseries index and random data in 5 columns:
ts = pd.date_range('2016-12-05', periods=180, freq='T')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(len(ts), 5), columns=[0,1,2,3,4], index=ts)

# Creating a `grouper` DataFrame, because don't want to change columns in `df`:
grouper = pd.DataFrame({'doy' : df.index.dayofyear,
                        'hr'  : df.index.hour}, index=df.index)
grouper['pd'] = pd.cut(grouper['hr'], bins=range(0, 25, 4), right=False)
```

---

---

```
# And now, to `groupby` using our `grouper`:
df.groupby(grouper['doy'], grouper['pd'])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
...
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

---

```
# Ok, try it another way:
df.groupby(grouper[['doy', 'pd']])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
...
ValueError: Grouper for '<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>' not 1-dimensional
```

---

```
# Another way:
df.groupby((grouper['doy'], grouper['pd']))
# Or equivalently:
df.groupby([grouper['doy'], grouper['pd']])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
...
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'
```

How, if there is a way, can I group a DataFrame using another DataFrame?

---

#### Working, but not solution:

Note that this works, but is not the solution I am looking for:

```
grouper['doy-pd'] = grouper[['doy', 'pd']].apply(lambda x: '{0}-{1}'.format(x['doy'],x['pd']), axis=1)
df.groupby(grouper['doy-pd'])
```

Because it does not give a `MultiIndex` after `groupby().apply()`

---

## Note

The issue was specific to `pandas 0.19.0`. The following works after upgrade to `0.19.1`:

```
df.groupby([grouper['doy'], grouper['pd']])
```

Also, it was a [working solution in `0.17.x`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34099371/3765319).

**Closing question because it was a version specific bug.**

Comment: Which pandas version are you using? I am not getting an error with `0.19.1`

Comment: @Psidom, what's your code? I am on 0.19.0. Perhaps I should close this question if the upgrade solves the problem, because then the issue would be a bug and not a programming question...

Comment: `df.groupby([grouper['doy'], grouper['pd']]).mean()` doesn't give me an error. I am on python 3.5 btw.

Comment: I'm on Python 3.5.2... It works after upgrade, so closing question, with a note. Thanks @Psidom!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was caused by a version specific bug. Upgrading pandas solved the problem.